# Draw a picture of a cube with edges a+b, and show it cut by planes that divide each edge into a segment of length a and a segment of length b.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am reading through 4 pillars of geometry and I need some help with this question.

Draw a picture of a cube with edges a+b, and show it cut by planes (parallel
to its faces) that divide each edge into a segment of length a and a segment
of length b.

Can someone draw a rough outline of this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a *very* rough outline, as requested.
[image]

Comment: This is so rough im getting splinters